# Access child ref from parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying access child ref from parent. I tried already in this ways:

1.
PARENT

```
someMethod() { 
   console.log(this.$refs.someChildCompontentRef.$refs) // {} 
}
```

2. 

CHILD

```
mounted(){ 
   this.$emit('setRef', $this.refs.someRef); 
}
```

PARENT

```
setRef(ref) { 
  console.log(ref) // undefinded don't know why? 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess:

The virtual DOM is already builded up but the real DOM isnt. So you need to wait till its builded up:

```
async mounted(){ 
   await this.$nextTick()
   this.$emit('setRef', $this.refs.someRef); 
}
```